# Federated learning : convert my own image dataset into tff simulation Clientdata

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

here is the code of my federated learning test

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import os
import collections
import warnings
from six.moves import range
import numpy as np
import six
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_federated as tff
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau, ModelCheckpoint
import PIL


#pretrain

train_datagen1 = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(vertical_flip=True)
training_set1= train_datagen1.flow_from_directory('folder1/train',target_size=(200, 200), batch_size=32)



)
```

Now when I want to create sample_batch like the tutorial in the tensorflow federtaed for image classification

I write this line and it find this error

```
example_dataset = training_set1.create_tf_dataset_for_client(training_set1.client_ids[0])
```

the error

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      1 training_set1.element_type_structure
----> 2 example_dataset = training_set1.create_tf_dataset_for_client(training_set1.client_ids[0])

TypeError: 'abstractproperty' object does not support indexing

---

Can you tell me how I must do to create dummy_batch in order to convert keras model into tff.learning.from_compiled_keras_model(model, dummy_batch)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your interest in TFF!

Generally, TFF is designed to ingest [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?version=stable) objects, so the example above needs a little extra preprocessing.

Good news is, there is an [existing tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) showing an example of doing this. In the above, something like the following should work:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    img_gen.flow_from_directory, args=[<your_directory>], 
    output_types=<your_types>, 
    output_shapes=<your_shapes>
)
```

Generally, one can think about the `ClientData` object as being a fancy `dict` mapping client ids to `tf.data.Datasets`. `ClientData` itself is an abstract class, and so can't be directly instantiated, and classmethods are provided to construct real instantiations of `ClientData`. One such classmethod that should work here would be `tff.simulation.ClientData.from_clients_and_fn`. Here, if you pass a list of `client_ids` and a function which returns the appropriate dataset when given a client id, you will have your hands on a fully functional `ClientData`.

I think here, an approach for defining the function you may use is to construct a Python `dict` which maps client IDs to `tf.data.Dataset` objects--you could then define a function which takes a client id, looks up the dataset in the dict, and returns the dataset.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: It should be a batch of data with the shape and type that the Keras model expects *if it were trained locally*, so if I am interpreting your question correctly, it should *not* be nested. In particular, the dummy batch is used to call the `train_on_batch` method from the underlying Keras model (since Keras instantiates some attributes lazily).