# How to load Fashion MNIST dataset in Tensorflow Fedarated?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I am working on a project with Tensorflow federated. I have managed to use the libraries provided by TensorFlow  Federated Learning simulations in order to load,  train, and test some datasets.

For example, i load the emnist dataset

```
emnist_train, emnist_test = tff.simulation.datasets.emnist.load_data()
```

and it got the data sets returned by load_data() as instances of tff.simulation.ClientData. This is an interface that allows me to iterate over client ids and allow me to select subsets of the data for simulations.

```
len(emnist_train.client_ids)

3383


emnist_train.element_type_structure


OrderedDict([('pixels', TensorSpec(shape=(28, 28), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)), ('label', TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))])


example_dataset = emnist_train.create_tf_dataset_for_client(
    emnist_train.client_ids[0])
```

I am trying to load the fashion_mnist dataset with Keras to perform some federated operations:

```
fashion_train,fashion_test=tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

but I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'element_spec'
```

because Keras returns a Tuple of Numpy arrays instead of a tff.simulation.ClientData like before:

```
def tff_model_fn() -> tff.learning.Model:
    return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
        keras_model=factory.retrieve_model(True),
        input_spec=fashion_test.element_spec,
        loss=loss_builder(),
        metrics=metrics_builder())

iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
    tff_model_fn, Parameters.server_adam_optimizer_fn, Parameters.client_adam_optimizer_fn)
server_state = iterative_process.initialize()
```

To sum up,

1. Is any way to create tuple elements of `tff.simulation.ClientData` from Keras Tuple Numpy arrays?
2. Another solution that comes to my mind is to use the
   `tff.simulation.HDF5ClientData` and load
   manually the appropriate files in a`HDF5`format `(train.h5,   test.h5)` in order to get the `tff.simulation.ClientData`, but my problem is that i cant find the url for fashion_mnist  `HDF5` file format i mean something like that for both train and test:

   ```
         fileprefix = 'fed_emnist_digitsonly'
         sha256 = '55333deb8546765427c385710ca5e7301e16f4ed8b60c1dc5ae224b42bd5b14b'
         filename = fileprefix + '.tar.bz2'
         path = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
             filename,
             origin='https://storage.googleapis.com/tff-datasets-public/' + filename,
             file_hash=sha256,
             hash_algorithm='sha256',
             extract=True,
             archive_format='tar',
             cache_dir=cache_dir)

         dir_path = os.path.dirname(path)
         train_client_data = hdf5_client_data.HDF5ClientData(
             os.path.join(dir_path, fileprefix + '_train.h5'))
         test_client_data = hdf5_client_data.HDF5ClientData(
             os.path.join(dir_path, fileprefix + '_test.h5'))

         return train_client_data, test_client_data
   ```

My final goal is to make the fashion_mnist dataset work with the TensorFlow federated learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track. To recap: the datasets returned by [`tff.simulation.dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/datasets) APIs are [`tff.simulation.ClientData`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/ClientData) objects. The object returned by [`tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/fashion_mnist/load_data) is a `tuple` of numpy arrays.

So what is needed is to implement a `tff.simulation.ClientData` to wrap the dataset returned by `tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data`. Some previous questions about implementing `ClientData` objects:

- [Federated learning : convert my own image dataset into tff simulation Clientdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59741397/federated-learning-convert-my-own-image-dataset-into-tff-simulation-clientdata)
- [How define tff.simulation.ClientData.from_clients_and_fn Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60265798/tff-how-define-tff-simulation-clientdata-from-clients-and-fn-function)
- [Is there a reasonable way to create tff clients datat sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58004272/is-there-a-reasonable-way-to-create-tff-clients-datat-sets/61675913#61675913)

This does require answering an important question: how should the Fashion MNIST data be split into individual users? The dataset doesn't include features that that could be used for partitioning. Researchers have come up with a few ways to synthetically partition the data, e.g. randomly sampling some labels for each participant, but this will have a great effect on model training and is useful to invest some thought here.